# Managing EhCache on multiple machines

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, distributed-system

I am running an app on multiple machines (for instance 2), in which each of them has `net.sf.ehcache`. the cache is
 updating great just on one of the machines, but cache on the other machines are not affected.

What is the best practice to synchronize between the caches, and what are the options that `net.sf.ehcache` expose.

[image]

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: @Kayaman, yes a lot of people recommended using JMS. what do you think ?

Comment: They seem to have pretty good documentation regarding replication on their homepage. I'm not sure why you're not reading official documentation, instead of recommendations by strangers.

Comment: @Kayaman The one who recommended the JMS is an Architect btw :), anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: The people at EhCache are pretty clear on which replication strategy they recommend. I understand that you might be impressed when a stranger on the Internet tells you they're an architect, but I'd still trust the people who wrote the thing more.

Comment: @Kayaman an architect I know in person.

Comment: So you know in person an architect who gave you bad advice. Congratulations. To both of you. You know what, you should both go read the documentation together. Then you'll both know better.

Comment: I don't know why you're taking it so serious, I asked about best practices. people may benifit from the answers.  If you can't help, then don't. no big deal.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an alternative to reading the documentation. I don't know why you claim that you've done research, when you clearly haven't read the official documentation. Instead you tell stories about an architect you know, who gave you bad advice. Seriously, I wasn't kidding when I suggested you both read the documentation. If your architect friend is suggesting JMS, then he's clearly not up to date. People don't benefit from answers to questions like this, since things change. What was valid today may not be valid a year from now, so **always read the official documentation**.

Comment: @Kayaman still you're not helping, there's a bunch of options. but there's nothing about the pros and cons of each one.
And btw, EhCache support replicated caching using JMS. http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/replication/jms-replicated-caching.html, so JMS isn't out of the game at all.

Comment: I never said EhCache doesn't support replication through JMS. But take a look at the most recent version's documentation and see. It shouldn't be *that* complicated for a software developer, even if there are "bunch of options".

Answer (score 3):

EhCache supports clustered caching via Terracotta, see http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.4/clustered-cache.html

But if you can choose your caching provider you may want to have a look at [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org/) or [Redis](https://redis.io/) as well. They may be better solutions if you need a distributed cache.